# Trying to understand what a systemd target wants

Tags: systemd

I am trying to get a better understanding of how target units in systemd work and am confused about what graphical.target "wants".

If I run `ls -l` in `/etc/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants` I see:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jul 19 16:50 accounts-daemon.service -> /lib/systemd/system/accounts-daemon.service
```

If I run `ls -l` in `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants` I see:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jul 12 11:28 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service -> ../systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
```

The file `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target` contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=Graphical Interface
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=display-manager.service
Conflicts=rescue.service rescue.target
After=multi-user.target rescue.service rescue.target display-manager.service
AllowIsolate=yes
```

Finally, if I run `systemctl show --property "Wants" graphical.target` I get:

```
Wants=hddtemp.service ureadahead.service speech-dispatcher.service systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service grub-common.service ntp.service lxdm.service accounts-daemon.service ondemand.service
```

Which source of "wants" in authoritative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The effective dependencies of a unit file are combined from a number of sources. For `graphical.target`, they are:

- `Wants=` statements in the `graphical.target` file itself (note that the unit file itself may be placed in various directories under `/lib`, `/run` or `/etc`, which shadow one another in this order);
- `Wants=` statements in so-called drop-in files in `$PREFIX/systemd/system/graphical.target.d/*.conf` (where PREFIX is as above and equally named drop-in files shadow each other individually);
- symlinks to wanted units in special directories in `$PREFIX/systemd/system/graphical.target.wants` (again, PREFIX is as above).

The dependencies from all these sources are simply added up, plus there is a number of implicit dependencies (read [systemd.target(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.target.html#Automatic%20Dependencies) for details).

So, to see effective dependencies, it is best to use the `systemctl show-property -p Wants` command. Unfortunately, there is no way to see which dependencies come from which places — you will have to check this manually if you want to remove one.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know if the command changed or if the command is different on my distribution (CentOS 7) but to check the dependencies for the graphical target I had to use this command: `systemctl show -p Wants graphical.target`

Comment: @newmangt The `show-property` subcommand has since been renamed to `show`, correct.